# Spring Boot Start Cache Not triggering

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-boot

I am running a spring boot 1.5.2 app.
I wanted to add caching to my service methods
I have added the spring-boot-starter-cache maven dependency and I am using the @ Cacheable annotations but it is not taking effect
I created my service beans in a @ Configuration class - here is an example

```
@Bean(name = "policyService")
public IPolicyService policyService() {
    policyService = new PolicyServiceImpl();
    return policyService;
}
```

Here is an example of my service method

```
@Cacheable(value="policiesCache")
    public List<PolicyDBO> findAllPolicies() {
        LOG.info("Entered findAllPolicies");

        List<PolicyDBO> policyList = policyRespoitory.findAll();

        LOG.info("Exiting findAllPolicies");
        return policyList;
    }
```

My repoistory interface method is as follows

```
@Repository
public interface PolicyRepository extends CrudRepository<PolicyDBO, Long>{

    /** Find policy by id **/
    PolicyDBO findById(Long policyId);
}
```

Whenever I call this service method from a RestController - the caching is never triggered - it looks like it is not setup properly

Any ideas what I can do to get caching setup correctly?

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that caching is active, Spring Caching is working *correctly*, but not as you expect. `@Cacheable` caches arguments against results.

In your case, the cache is storing `no arguments` against the result of `List<PolicyDBO>`.

However when you call `findById`, the cache doesn't find anything against an argument of `Long` and so doesn't return a cached result.